# How do I delete the property number?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Student(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear)
{
     this.name = name;
     this.sclass = sclass;
     this.year = year;
     this.number = number;
     this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
}

// Edit : added OP's code from comments
let Manuel = new Student("Manuel", "lesi", "3", "98789", 2014);
console.log(Manuel.number);
delete Student.number;
console.log(Student); // The object still includes number as property
```

How do I delete the property number, as the delete Student.number is not working.

Comment: what do you mean its not working? **elaborate**

Comment: You're only defining a function, not executing it or instanciating it. This code doesn't seem enough to help

Comment: `var k = new Student(); delete k.number;`

Comment: Student is a class, not an object.

Comment: `let Manuel = new Student("Manuel", "lesi", "3", "98789", 2014)`
`console.log(Manuel.number);`
`delete Student.number`
`console.log(Student);`
 // The object still includes number as property

Comment: Just `delete Manuel.number`.

Comment: You cannot delete `Student.number` because there is no `Student.number`. It exists only on the instances of `Student`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...as the delete Student.number is not working

`Student` has no `number` property, so there's nothing to delete. Objects created with `new Student` do. So for instance:

```js
function Student(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.sclass = sclass;
    this.year = year;
    this.number = number;
    this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
}

var s = new Student();
console.log("number" in s); // true
delete s.number;
console.log("number" in s); // false
```

If you want to create a version of `Student` that creates objects without a `number` property, that's *possible*, but it's a bad idea:

```js
function Student(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.sclass = sclass;
    this.year = year;
    this.number = number;
    this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
}

function NumberlessStudent() {
    Student.apply(this, arguments);
    delete this.number;
}
NumberlessStudent.prototype = Object.create(Student.prototype);
NumberlessStudent.prototype.constructor = NumberlessStudent;

var n = new NumberlessStudent();
console.log("number" in n); // false
```

Or preferably in ES2015+ with `class` syntax:

```js
class Student {
    constructor(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sclass = sclass;
        this.year = year;
        this.number = number;
        this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
    }
}

class NumberlessStudent extends Student {
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        delete this.number;
    }
}

const n = new NumberlessStudent();
console.log("number" in n); // false
```

It's a bad idea because setting up inheritance in that way, subclass instances (`NumberlessStudent`) should have the features of superclass (`Student`) instances.

Answer (score 5):

Your `Student` is a constructor, so `Student.number` is not correct unless it is a static method (but this is not your case).

You have to create an object of `Student`, i.e.

```
const student = new Student('Mell', 'A', 1990, 500, 1994);
```

Then you can use

```
delete student.number
```

See this snippet as an example:

```js
function Student(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear)
{
     this.name = name;
     this.sclass = sclass;
     this.year = year;
     this.number = number;
     this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
}

// Edit : added OP's code from comments
let Manuel = new Student("Manuel", "lesi", "3", "98789", 2014);

console.log('Number:', Manuel.number);
delete Manuel.number;
console.log('Number:', Manuel.number);
```

You can find more information about constructors and objects in JavaScript [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Here Student is instance of student

```
delete Student.number;
```

// Example 2

```
delete Student[number];
```

// Example 3

```
delete Student["number"];
```

you can delete the object key with the above example. but keep in mind Student should be instance rather than Function Object

Comment: `Student[number]` --> number is undefined

Comment: It should be `delete Student['number']`.

Answer (score 2):

You are expecting `this` to be the function itself.
This is true only if you call it with the `new` keyword.

This should work:

```
var s = new Student('Gil', 'AAA', 2019, 123, 2018);
console.log(s.number); // prints 123
delete s.number;
console.log(s.number); // prints undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

you're applying the delete method on the `constructor` . you should applied on the `instance` `Manuel` instead of the `Student` `constructors`

```js
function Student(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sclass = sclass;
  this.year = year;
  this.number = number;
  this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
}

// Edit : added OP's code from comments
let Manuel = new Student("Manuel", "lesi", "3", "98789", 2014);
console.log(Manuel.number);
delete Manuel.number;
console.log(Manuel);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
let Manuel = new Student("Manuel", "lesi", "3", "98789", 2014) 
console.log(Manuel.number);
delete Manuel.number // if you try delete student.number then it not work
console.log(Manuel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `delete` to delete a property from an object. You cannot delete properties from `constructors`(Student in this case) but you can delete it from objects. Create an object and using `delete`, delete the number property

```js
function Student(name, sclass, year, number, submissionYear)
{
     this.name = name;
     this.sclass = sclass;
     this.year = year;
     this.number = number;
     this.submissionYear = submissionYear;
}

var a=new Student('a','3',3,4,6)
console.log(a)
delete a['number'];
console.log(a)
```